# Closure and thread-safety in await/async

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have some thoughts regarding thread safety in argument and closure capturing. I'll try to illustrate using examples.

**Example 1**

Consider the following code, taken from [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html):

```
private async void DownloadFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Since we asynchronously wait, the UI thread is not blocked by the file   download.
  await DownloadFileAsync(fileNameTextBox.Text);

  // Since we resume on the UI context, we can directly access UI elements.
  resultTextBox.Text = "File downloaded!";
}
```

What concerns me is that `fileNameTextBox.Text` is accessed by the UI thread, while `DownloadFileAsync(...)` will probably run on a thread-pool thread.

Is this code thread-safe? Is it because strings are immutable? What if the argument to `DownloadFileAsync()` was an array?

**Example 2**

Same question, but with closures. For example, is the following code thread safe?

```
private async void SomeAsyncCalculation(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        SomeCalculation(uiOwnedArray);
    }
}
```

I'm not, as `uiOwnedArray` is accessed from multiple threads without synchronization. How do I mitigate this?

Comment: `What if the argument to DownloadFileAsync() was an array?` It would be safe as long as nothing else was writing to the same array.

Comment: `How do I mitigate this?` Use `lock`. Or change `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        SomeCalculation(uiOwnedArray);
    }` to `var bob = uiOwnedArray.ToArray(); await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        SomeCalculation(bob); }` _The latter will solve some thread safety issues, but not all._

Comment: What do you mean by a "UI owned array"?

Comment: If `fileNameTextBox.Text` is thread-safe, then yes it should be thread-safe. And this applies to `uiOwnedArray` in the second code as well.

Comment: @hendryanw - I assume `fileNameTextBox.Text` is the `Text` property of some UI control, probably editable by the user. In this case, is it OK to pass it as in Example 1, even though nothing prevents the user from changing it while `DownloadFileButton_Click()` is running?

Comment: `fileNameTextBox.Text` isn't thread-safe generally @hendryanw . It is safe, in the specific example above, since it is only accessed from the UI thread.

Comment: @mjwills - are you sure? Depending on the Scheduler, it can also run on a thread-pool thread

Comment: @mjwills ah yeah, wow silly me. Yes the code will be executed by main thread or UI thread in this case, so it is safe.

Comment: @bavaza The UI thread should be the one who access the text, and then when it executes the asynchronous IO operation which is the download file in this case, it returns back to serve the UI and wait for the resume signal.